# Spinner - setAdapter causes memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-spinner

I have the below code, which sets up a simple spinner, however whenever I fire the setAdapter, my app crashes out due to a memory leak (memory heap just keeps growing until it hits OutOfMemoryException).

```
final ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        try {
            for (String file : assetManager.list("")) {
                if (file.endsWith(".plist")) items.add(file.replaceAll(".plist$", "")); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

        countrys.setAdapter(adp);
        countrys.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                readPlistContents(items.get(index) + ".plist");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

From the code, I can't see why this might be happening.

Comment: Are you getting error here  `countrys.setAdapter(adp);?`

Comment: Yes if i comment out that line the app does not crash it is certainly this line that is causing the leak

Comment: How much data in your assets folder? Means are there a much strings?

Comment: a mixture of .plist files and pdfs which total ~5MB

Comment: Then may be because of that you are getting error

Comment: Im confused why? what would my asset folder contents have to do with the error?

Comment: There are a pdf files to and also .plist contains more string . That cause a problem

Comment: But my for loop will only add the names of the .plist files to the array. The array also has the right content.

Comment: Add `android:largeHeap="true"` for your activity in manifest file.